# Is the intersection of two Noetherian rings Noetherian?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Is the intersection of two Noetherian rings also Noetherian?

If yes, could you please give me the idea of proof. If not, give me an counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

No!

Let $K\subset L$ be a field extension. It's well known and easily proven that $R=K+XL[X]$ is noetherian if and only if $[L:K]<\infty$.

Let $R_1=\mathbb F_2(Y^2+Y)+X\mathbb F_2(Y)[X]$, and $R_2=\mathbb F_2(Y^3+Y^2)+X\mathbb F_2(Y)[X]$. Then $R_1,R_2$ are noetherian, while $R_1\cap R_2=\mathbb F_2+X\mathbb F_2(Y)[X]$ is not.